# How to getting a reference to elements within the container of an angular structural directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-template-variable

I have the following template with a test structural directive called `*appUnless`:

```
<h1 *appUnless>
  <app-hello></app-hello>
  <input type="text" value="hello" />
</h1>
```

Inside of my structural directive, so far I have this:

```
import {
  Directive,
  Input,
  TemplateRef,
  ViewContainerRef,
} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[appUnless]",
})
export class UnlessDirective {
  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
  ) {}

  @Input()
  set appUnless(message: string) {
    const embeddedViewRef = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(
      this.templateRef
    );
  }
}
```

How do I get a reference to the `input` element from within the directive? I want to be able to refer to the `input` no different than if I had placed a template reference declaration on it, i.e., if I were to do `<input #myInput>`. Obviously, since I don't control the contents of what is placed inside of the container, I can't place `#myInput` into the template.

Also, how do I get a reference to the `AppHelloComponent` (one that backs `app-hello`) with correct type from within this directive?